# How to make an opening divbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
<h3 id="3title">Aenean lacinia bibendum.</h3>
<p class="clear">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget.</p>
    <figure class="clear">
        <img src="img/klint-faaborg-chair.jpg" alt="Faaborg chair">
        <figcaption>Consectetur Fusce Quam</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

I want to add an opening div box before my h3 elements on my html page and a closing divbox after the `</figure>`

I have tried with:

```
<script>
    $( "h3" ).before( "<div class='startdiv'>" );
</script>
```

But it will output:

```
"<div class="startdiv"></div>"
```

before all me h3 elements.

What have I done wrong. 
How can I only make an opening div box before all the h3 elements?

Comment: You should use `$("h3").wrap('<div class="startdiv"></div>')`.

Comment: I have edit the question.
I want to include all that in a div box.

Comment: Since you have multiple `h3`, how can we know after which `figure` should `</div>` be placed? Or it's always `h3 + p + figure`?

Comment: Yes it is always "h3 + p + figure" want to wrap that into a div box

Comment: You should wrap your content with the #startdiv in your html and then just use Javascript to give the feature you want .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you are after with this code:

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('figure + *').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='startdiv'>");
});
```

Check the test demo below.

```js
$('h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('figure + *').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='startdiv'>");
});
```

```css
.startdiv {
    background: #EEE;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h3 id="3title">Aenean lacinia bibendum.</h3>
    <p class="clear">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget.</p>
    <figure class="clear">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="Faaborg chair" />
        <figcaption>Consectetur Fusce Quam</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <h3 id="3title">Aenean lacinia bibendum.</h3>
    <p class="clear">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget.</p>
    <figure class="clear">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="Faaborg chair" />
        <figcaption>Consectetur Fusce Quam</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You are manipulating the `DOM`.
It's not possible just to insert an opening element. The browser will automatically fix it for you.

Instead you should find a better solution (trust me, there is one) for your use case (e.g. jQuery's [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function).